# How Can I Rar a File with a Unicode Name in Batch

Tags: windows, shell, winrar

I wrote a small batch file to rar all contents in all subfolders within a folder. It works fine except for that the file names should be in ASCII. Below is the working small code:

```
@REM ------- BEGIN rarthem.bat ----------------
@setlocal
@echo off
echo --------------------------------------------------
echo Starting to rar files
echo --------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo.
set path="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\";%path%
for /D /r %%G in ("*") do (
    echo Storing files in %%G
    echo --------------------------------------------------

    cd %%G

    for %%I in (*.*) do (
        rar a -x*.rar -x*.zip -m0 -id[c] "%%~nI.rar" "%%I"
        echo Done archiving %%~nI%%~xI
    )

    echo --------------------------------------------------
    echo Done archiving %%~nG
    echo --------------------------------------------------
    echo.
    echo.
    cd ..
)

echo Finished!
pause
REM ------- END rarthem.bat ------------------
```

I think the problem happens when the file name is parsed to WinRAR as WinRAR has no problem archiving files with Unicode names.

Edit: When parsing the file name to WinRAR, the file name gets modified so when WinRAR tries to look for the file under that name, it can't find it. For example a file: téxt.pdf will become text.pdf when parsed.

A small side question: I've not tried using 7zip, would it be easier to achieve the same thing with 7zip?

Many thanks for help.

Comment: What kind of change are you seeing? You say the file names should be in ASCII, but you say that they are Unicode. Do you want them to be converted somehow? A test using 7zip preserves Unicode characters. I don't have rar.

Comment: Sorry I was vague. I added more info. I just would like to be able rar the file without having to change its name. Probably I'd give 7zip a try.

Comment: 7-zip will do it if you want to create a .7z archive. RAR.exe and WinRAR.exe are the only things that will create an actual RAR archive. (7-Zip can unpack RAR but not create it. The people who make RAR will still only licence an unpacking library to anyone else after all these years, which is quite frustrating if you want to use (or create) a better tool for creating RARs.)

Comment: I wrote a similar batch to compress files using 7z. I can confirm that 7z, as Dennis said, has no problem with unicode file names - also this implies that batch can cope with unicode. Thanks again to Leo and Dennis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAR.exe processes its command-line in the OEM character set (i.e. not unicode). The only way I know of to pass a unicode name to it is via a list file, when also using the argument to specify that the list file is unicode. However, that only works for files *inside* the archive (EDIT: or files you want to add to the archive). For the archive name itself I don't know of a solution except...

If you use WinRAR.exe instead of RAR.exe then you can pass unicode filenames on the command-line and they work fine. You will see a GUI progress window but other than that  (which may or may not matter to you) WinRAR.exe is suitable for running from batch scripts.

Whether a batch script itself can cope with unicode I do not know, but if that is the only problem remaining I would switch to using VBScript or JScript instead of a batch file. (Which is worth doing anyway, IMO. I'm not a big fan of VBScript and JScript but at least they don't have completely insane, arcane semantics and limitations like batch does. :))

By the way, if you do use WinRAR.exe you might want to get the recent WinRAR 4 (beta 2 currently) as it includes the ability to specify the working directory, previously only possible with rar.exe. That can be essential if you need to add files from read-only directories.

If you want to learn about the list files I mentioned, check the RAR.exe text-file document or the WinRAR.exe built-in online help for all the details.

Hope that helps!